# Typical Linq-to-SQL Join situation - best practices?

Tags: c#, performance, join, linq-to-sql

It is possible to write same 'Join' thing in few ways using Linq-to-SQL. Is it any performance difference? What are best practices?

Either:

```
database.Orders.
    Where(o => o.S == s).
    Join(database.OrderEvents.Where(e => e.B == b),
        o => o, e => e.Order, (o, e) => o).
    ToArray();
```

Or:

```
database.Orders.
    Where(o => o.S == s).
    Join(database.OrderEvents,
        o => o, e => e.Order, (o, e) => new { O = o, E = e }).
    Where(a => a.E.b == b).
    Select(a => a.O).
    ToArray();
```

Or:

```
database.Orders.
    Join(database.OrderEvents,
        o => o, e => e.Order, (o, e) => new { O = o, E = e }).
    Where(a => a.O.S == s && a.E.b == b).
    Select(a => a.O).
    ToArray();
```

Comment: _Is it any performance differences?_ From Eric Lippert: **If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then race your horses.** http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: 'If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then race your horses.' -- maybe someone has raced them already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ran 1 and 3 versions of the code under a profiler. SQL query is the same except an order of params and conditions in WHERE clause. So, performance is the same. What about readability?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply say which query does a better job. To do so, you have to trace the generated SQL statement and analyse it.

All three linq statements might at the end produce pretty similar SQL statements, if so, you will not see any performance difference.

If the linq statements do actually generate different SQL statements you can check the performance with sql tools, looking at the query plan etc.

Maybe you will still not see any performance differences because SQL Server optimizes the query plan for you...

So no, there is usually no best practice except from the fact that you have to do the job of analyzing the generated queries if you want to fine tune your application or if you want to figure out performance issues...